# calculate and display result from a row in codeignitor 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table where i need to subtract tow values in the same column and display the difference in another view table. I need to record daily total hour meter readings from 5 compressors and display the difference as daily running hours.

My table: 
[image output of crudtabe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBh84.png)

```
SELECT a.cuidad_id,
       a.bc100a,
       Coalesce(a.bc100a - (SELECT b.bc100a
                            FROM   cuidadrun b
                            WHERE  a.cuidad_id = b.cuidad_id + 1), a.bc100a) AS
       diffbc100a
FROM   cuidadrun a
```

what is working great in phpmyadmin, please see image:
[sql output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBNDk.png)

I cant workout my controller, model, and view to display the result.
also, can i save the result in another table?

My Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cactushrs extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Cactushrs_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('template/header');
    $data = $this->Cactushrs_model->cactushrs();
    $this->load->view('pages/cactushrs_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

My Model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cactushrs_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
  public function cactushrs()
  {

    $query = $this->db->get ('SELECT a.cuidad_id, a.bc100a, COALESCE(a.bc100a - (SELECT b.bc100a FROM cuidadrun b WHERE a.cuidad_id = b.cuidad_id + 1), a.bc100a) AS differnce FROM cuidadrun a');

  }
}
```

My view

```
<table id="cuidadhrs" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>cuidad_id</th>
          <th>bc100a</th>
          <th>diff100</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $this->db->get('differnce'); ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

DB Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSM6hA2Wa3cpRJAqEoDMKZ/0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solved my question myself. The problem was in the model, controller and view.

controller.php

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cuidadhrs extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->model('Cuidadhrs_model');
        $hours['hours'] = $this->Cuidadhrs_model->cuidadhrs();
        $this->load->view('pages/cuidadhrs_view', $hours);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

model.php

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cuidadhrs_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
  public function cuidadhrs()
  {

    $sql = "SELECT a.cuidad_id, a.bc100a, COALESCE(a.bc100a - (SELECT b.bc100a FROM cuidadrun b WHERE a.cuidad_id = b.cuidad_id + 1), a.bc100a) AS diffbc100a FROM cuidadrun a";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();

  }
}
```

view.php

```
    <table id="cuidadhrs" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>BC-100a Hourmeter</th>
        <th>Daily Hrs.</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach($hours as $hrs){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $hrs['cuidad_id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $hrs['bc100a']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $hrs['diffbc100a']; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); ?>
</table>
```